# Microsoft.Web/sites resource provider return an InternalServerError status when integrating Managed Service Identities

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-managed-identity

After seeing the article [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service/app-service-managed-service-identity) about integrating Managed Service Identities (MSI) with Azure AppService I wanted to give it a try.

I have inserted the new identity member inside my `Microsoft.Web/sites` resource like instructed in the article.

```
"identity": {
  "type": "SystemAssigned"
}
```

But now when I deploy the template, my web apps are failing with the following error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "ResourceDeploymentFailure",
    "message": "The response for resource had empty or invalid content."
  }
 }
```

The resource seems to deploy fine and MSI is now activated but I have this error and it failed my template deployment.

I have tested the deployment for this resource type using `apiVersion` `2016-03-01` & `2016-08-01` and I get the same error.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi - I'm from the App Service team. What you have seems correct, so we'd like to investigate on the backend. Could you follow the instructions on this page to help us out? https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Reporting-your-site-name-without-posting-it-publicly

Comment: Sorry I didn't got the notification for your reply.

You can check the app service plan where dummy23765.azurewebsites.net is located. There are multiple web apps on this ASP and they all act the same way when performing the deployment so anyone of them should do the trick.

Comment: @mattchenderson did you got any chance to take a look at this?

Comment: We think this is due to a known bug around ARM schema validation. Do you happen to have any outputs from the site in your ARM template?

Comment: Do you mean an outputs in the template that reference the site? Yes I do in the outputs section of my ARM template. But since the template deployment fails, Outputs aren't processed. I ran another deployment today fora new environment, same results, here are the details:

`OPERATION ID: BAE874F6088990BF`
`TRACKING ID: ae06eb3c-8e75-484f-ab55-9448454794c4`
`TIMESTAMP: 10/6/2017, 7:08:16 AM`

I created a new dummy site so you can track the real site (ov-sbox-webapp-web-xxxxxxxxxx) in question: _dummy2384764_

Let me know if you need to take this offline for more troubleshooting

Comment: To close the loop, the team fixed a bug on their end that was causing this, it has now been fixed.